# Report generated as HTML view, Can print as it is?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my application I wanted to generate the final report more stylish way and currently I used to show the report in HTML/CSS view.

Then I wanted to try it printing, but when it does, it's comes with the basic view (like no tables, data not arranged well etc). So I want to know that is it possible to send this view to the print as it is shown in the view?.

I found a javascript for printing action and this is I used for print.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintElem(elem) {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data) {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'divprint', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
        /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }

</script>
```

Or is there way to convert this to pdf when user click to the print and then open that pdf for print? I also want to set this view to A4 size when generating it.

This is how my view shows as now . Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you try [html2pdf](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-html2pdf)?

Comment: @AlexYu Nope. Is it a addon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this library to your project,
download link: https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/

HTML Code:

```
<div id="dPDF">
   Your all html here which you want to print
</div>

<div class="generate-pdf" onclick="downloadPDF()">
    Generate PDF (Button for generating pdf)
</div>
```

function for generating PDF:

```
function downloadPDF() {
        const element = document.getElementById("dPDF");

        var opt = {
            margin: 0.5,
            filename: 'your_filename.pdf',
            image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
            html2canvas: { scale: 4, logging: true },
            jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' }
        };

        html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();
    }
```

Note: By generating and downloading pdf you can print the exact view you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried it and it worked. :)

Comment: welcome brother.